# Relative path File not found exception

Tags: java, relative-path, filenotfoundexception

I am working on a simple web application in NetBeans where I am getting FileNotFoundException. I have stored files in class path, so I need to use relative paths. When I tried with absolute path, it worked fine for me.

Below image shows my file system hierarchy.

[image]

I need to write content data in file DBList.txt.

My code is:

```
File file = new File("data/application/DBList.txt");
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)));
```

I have searched lot but not getting solution for reading file using relative path.

Comment: The folder `data` does not seem to be on your classpath. How are you running your program?

Comment: How is folder `data` in your classpath ? Show us the `build.xml` ! Also `WEB-INF\classes` !

Comment: i have tried by putting it in src->data->application->DBList.txt but it gives same error..

Comment: The file system is different than the classpath.

Answer (score 5):

The path is relative to the working directory of the *server*, not your project in NetBeans. Given your FNFE I suspect that the directory structure `data/application/` doesn't exist under the working directory.

What server are you running and how are you starting it? You can figure out the server's working directory by logging;

```
File wd = new File(".");
log.debug("working dir: " + wd.getAbsolutePath());
```

**Edit:**
The `File` class and the classpath are totally unrelated concepts. Don't confuse the two. If you are looking to use classpath resources have a look at the [`getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) method in [`ClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html).

Answer (score -4):

try to use "\\" instead of "/"